# How can I connect to wifi Internet using IP rather than ESSID?

Tags: terminal, wifi, configuration, internet

How can I connect to wifi Internet using IP rather than ESSID?

Hello,

I have a machine running a Linux OS and I want to connect to Internet over wifi. However, I do not want to use the ESSID in the configuration settings. Instead, I want to connect to the IP address using password only.

I. e. I know the IP of the access point and I want to put only the IP and the password into e. g. WPA_supplicant.conf or similar Internet settings file. I will only use the Terminal for this so please don't reply with any GUI instructions.

Is it possible and if so, how?

Vesa

Comment: are you looking for wifi setup with hidden ssid?

Comment: No, I am using VPN's so I don't have a real ESSID every time. Sometimes I can only see the IP address of the VPN tunnel so that's what I got to work with. I have tried to ping the tunnel and it responds, so I want to test if I can connect to it. Not sure if it's possible but I want to try.

Comment: to ping an IP, you must already be part of the network.

Comment: Yes, well it's the same network, sort of. The setup is a bit complicated. But I still need to know how, if possible, to route my Internet connection through that VPN tunnel which doesn't have an ESSID.